# Why is `brew` extremely slow?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

When I run `brew --version`, it took 30 seconds to return a response. Other `brew` commands are even slower. My CPU is ~ 90% idle. All other programs are running perfectly fine on my machine. I have the latest version of brew, and brew doctor passes.

Any ideas on what I can try (other than reboot the machine)?

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.5.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision bda76; last commit 2018-02-26)

$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.

$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.5.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 021fe22e3c982b08346422d1e7897e929a709380
Last commit: 2 weeks ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: bda76108c4f452684682a89f1d7fb7cd4acf8557
Core tap last commit: 4 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS_THIS_RUN: 1
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.0 build 900
Git: 2.15.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: N/A
macOS: 10.12.6-x86_64
Xcode: N/A
CLT: 9.2.0.0.1.1510905681
X11: N/A
```

Comment: What is your PATH?

Comment: `echo $PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. `which brew` is
`/usr/local/bin/brew`

Comment: Looks like a network timeout of some sort. Try unmounting network volumes if any and disconnecting from the network to see if this improves the situation. Another thing would be issues with the git repo, check for a safe way to reset it.

Comment: I ran out of patience and just rebooted my machine, which resolved the problem. You may be right that it could have been a network timeout or git issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a network issue.
In such cases when I use a framework that is dependant on the internet I would run a ping test which can give a clue on what's happening on the network layer (any delays or such)